# how to center and make various images sizes fit in a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I'm using bxslider to have a carousel of images. The thing is though, the images it receives to display are of somewhat unpredictable sizes. The container size is 243x243. And we know that no image will have a side smaller than 243. So...I'd like to center the image in the container. And either zoom in until the shorter of the two dimensions (L vs W) fills the container at 243, and the longer dimension overflow is hidden.

For the images I'm working with, doing this will be perfect for getting the important details of the picture in the frame.

But I'm having trouble...

I've tried the following to center the picture in the frame:

```
jQuery(".bx-container").each(function() {
 var img_w = jQuery(this).children("img").width();
 var img_h = jQuery(this).children("img").height();
 var pos_top = (img_h - containerHeight) / 2;
 var pos_left = (img_w - containerWidth) / 2;

 var pos_top = (243 - img_h) / 2;
 var pos_left = (243 - img_w) / 2;

 jQuery(this).children("img").css({
     'top' : pos_top + 'px',
     'left' : pos_left + 'px'
 });
});
```

And I've tried this to position not square images into the frame:

```
jQuery(".bx-container").each(function(){

var refRatio = 1;

var imgH = jQuery(this).children("img").height();
var imgW = jQuery(this).children("img").width();

if ( (imgW/imgH) < refRatio ) { 
    jQuery(this).addClass("bx-portrait");
} else {
    jQuery(this).addClass("bx-landscape");
}
});
});
```

I've messed with both scripts and the css but I just can't seem to get it work. It either centers but doesn't resize right. Or resizes but centers wrong. Or does both wrong.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vgJ9X/298/

Could someone help me out?

Thanks!

EDIT:

New jsfiddle...the portrait ones work right. The landscape images still squish. :(

http://jsfiddle.net/vgJ9X/307/

EDIT:
I THINK it has something to do with relatively positioned elements not being allowed to overlap. Trying to find a fix. If anyone knows, edit the last fiddle I posted.

Comment: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/vgJ9X/309/) is your updated fiddle... my updated ans looks better IMHO..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 jQuery(".bx-container img").each(function () {
    var w = jQuery(this).width();
    var h = jQuery(this).height();
    if (w > h) $(this).addClass('bx-landscape');
    else $(this).addClass('bx-portrait');
});
```

Check this  [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/vgJ9X/303/)

**Update**

```
jQuery(".bx-container img").each(function () {
    var w = jQuery(this).width();
    var h = jQuery(this).height();
    if (w > h){
        $(this).addClass('bx-landscape');
        var trans= -243/2;
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform','translateZ('+trans+'px)');
    }
    else if(h > w){
        $(this).addClass('bx-portrait');
        var trans= -243/2;
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform','translateY('+trans+'px)');
    }
});
```

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/vgJ9X/306/)

**Update of Update**

Found the issue with landscape, the plugin is setting `max-width:100%;` overriding it with `max-width:none;` fixes the issue...

[Update Of Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/vgJ9X/314/)

Comment: I want avoid stretching images though. That's why I want to zoom-in/resize in a manner were the smaller edge fills the frame, and the longer edge is just hidden overflow.

Comment: the landscape ones still 'squish'.

i also made a new fiddle, slightly different approach. same result...portrait ones work, landscape ones don't.

http://jsfiddle.net/vgJ9X/307/

Comment: looks good! do you know if this will work on all popular browsers?

Comment: @user2747609 Adding few more lines as in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/vgJ9X/314) will make it work on everything from IE9+, moz 3.5+, chrome 4.0+ safari 3.1+ and opera 10.5+  check the full compatibility table [here](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d) would be nice of you to accept the answer if it solved the prob.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
img{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:300px;
}
```

Simple an clean.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vgJ9X/302/

Comment: This doesn't keep the aspect ratio of the images.

Answer (score 0):

I did a couple things to your jsfiddle.

First I changed the order of your `resize` and `center` functions, so the resize comes first. This way, the smaller images get resized, then centered. I also uncommented the first portion of your code.

You also had a couple of errors in your css. There was an extra closing bracket after `img` style declaration. Your `.bx-portrait img` and `.bx-landscape img` declarations were set to `100%px;`.

**Update:**

Change the css in your two .bx classes to:

```
.bx-portrait img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
.bx-landscape img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And add a clearfix to your ul:

```
.bxslider:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

The height is clipping because `.bx-viewport` has a set height of `243px` but also has a `5px border`, which makes the actual internal height `233px`. You'll need to make the height `253px` to account for the `10px` of border. This is why they don't look centered vertically.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vgJ9X/304/)**

Comment: It looks like it's changing the aspect ration of some images. Or am I just imagining that? Looks like a at least one of those images look squished.

Comment: You're right. I've edited my answer to account for this. The added solution forces the images to maintain their aspect ratio and fill either height or width depending on which is larger. So a landscape image that is not 243px tall will fill 100% of the li width and center without filling the height.

Comment: The height is clipping because `.bx-viewport` has a set height of `243px` but also has a `5px border`, which makes the actual internal height `233px`. You'll need to make the height `253px` to account for the `10px` of border.

Comment: I'm getting closer. I've edited mine where the portrait ones work. But the landscape ones are crap.

http://jsfiddle.net/vgJ9X/307/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use background images instead and center them. Here is a demo from your original code

http://jsfiddle.net/8y8df/

If you want to show the full size image, just remove the `background-size:contain;` from the css.

Comment: changes aspect ration. :(

Comment: removing the background-size:contain; will fill the area with your image and clip it.

Comment: i don't know if backgrounds are going to work for me. i've just never used the css background attribute to display a gallery, with which i need to do some dynamic things later on. i'll look into it to see if it may be viable.